# Quickly combine logical matrices with & in R

Tags: r, binary, vectorization, logical-operators, processing-efficiency

I have a large logical matrix and need to combine each column with a vector using the `&` operation. Right now I'm looping over the columns but this takes a while since there are over 1 million rows. Is there faster, possibly vectorized way to do this?

```
mx <- replicate(10, sample(c(T,F), size = 1000, replace = T)) # 1000 rows x 10 columns
bool <- sample(c(T,F), size = 1000, replace = T) # 1000 elements

out <- apply(mx1, 2, function(x) {
  x & bool
})
```

For context, this data is from a gene expression matrix where 1 row = 1 cell

Comment: `mx & bool` works, doesn't it?

Comment: @r2evans yes, I've checked that against the OP's code, and `all((mx & bool) == out)` is `TRUE`

Comment: Yeah, I can't believe I didn't just try this first. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy in this case:

```
mx & bool
```

`bool` is recycled for all the columns in `mx`

```
identical(mx & bool, out)
```

output:

```
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you're wanting a result the dims of `mx` that have each row `&`ed with the respective single value of `bool`. I think you're fine without doing anything externally.

```r
set.seed(42)
mx <- replicate(4, sample(c(T,F), size = 10, replace = T)) # 1000 rows x 10 columns
bool <- sample(c(T,F), size = 10, replace = T) # 1000 elements
cbind(mx, NA, bool)
#                                   bool
#  [1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE NA  TRUE
#  [2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE NA  TRUE
#  [3,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE NA  TRUE
#  [4,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE NA FALSE
#  [5,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE NA  TRUE
#  [6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE NA FALSE
#  [7,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE NA FALSE
#  [8,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE NA FALSE
#  [9,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE NA FALSE
# [10,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE NA FALSE
```

(Showing the `cbind`ed data just to align the `bool` values with each row of `mx`.)

With that, any row with `bool` false should result in all `FALSE`:

```r
mx & bool
#        [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
#  [1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#  [2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#  [3,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#  [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [5,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#  [6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [7,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [8,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [9,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [10,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Validation:

```r
out <- apply(mx, 2, function(x) x & bool)
identical(out, mx & bool)
# [1] TRUE
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(apply(mx, 2, function(x) x & bool), mx & bool)
# Unit: nanoseconds
#                                expr   min    lq  mean median    uq     max neval
#  apply(mx, 2, function(x) x & bool) 31100 32400 53029  34400 39750 1644700   100
#                           mx & bool   400   600   824    700   900    3200   100
```

Using your larger matrix:

```r
mx <- replicate(10, sample(c(T,F), size = 1000, replace = T)) # 1000 rows x 10 columns
bool <- sample(c(T,F), size = 1000, replace = T) # 1000 elements
dim(mx)
# [1] 1000   10
length(bool)
# [1] 1000

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(apply(mx, 2, function(x) x & bool), mx & bool)
# Unit: microseconds
#                                expr   min     lq    mean median     uq    max neval
#  apply(mx, 2, function(x) x & bool) 336.1 489.70 621.647 605.25 696.05 1999.9   100
#                           mx & bool  65.0  94.25 135.260 129.20 159.50  385.4   100
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the data.table package:

```
n <- 1000000
mx <- replicate(10, sample(c(T,F), size = n, replace = T)) # n rows x 10 columns
bool <- sample(c(T,F), size = n, replace = T) # n elements

# original solution
system.time(
  out <- apply(mx, 2, function(x) {
    x & bool
  })
)

# user  system elapsed 
# 0.20    0.02    0.22 


# using data.table, approx. half the time
dt <- data.table(mx)

system.time(
  out2 <- dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x){x & bool})]
)

# user  system elapsed 
# 0.11    0.00    0.11
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm a fan of data.table but I think the `mx & bool` solution is actually faster here

Comment: Agreed, I just tried it. I didn't know the `&` operator was vectorized by default; that's nice to know.

Comment: `&` is vectorized by definition and intent, in fact ... as opposed to `&&`, which is intentionally *not* vectorized